# What is the particle density for a Gaussian distribution in position and velocity?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Consider that the position and momentum of my particles have a Gaussian distribution.
If I now calculate the number of particles in
$dx$ with momentum $dp$ then which one of the following would it be:

$$d^2N=Ce^{-\frac{p^2}{2}}dxdp$$

or $$d^2N=Ce^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}e^{-\frac{p^2}{2}}dxdp$$

where in both cases $C$ is fixed by:
$$\int d^2N=N $$(N=total number of particles)

I think it's the second one because in $dx$ number of particles are $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$ and in $dp$ the number of particles are $e^{-\frac{p^2}{2}}dp$ so that the number of particles for both should be the product but my advisor wrote the first one so I am not sure how my reasoning is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two different distributions, which one is correct depends on the system of particles you are trying to describe.

In the first one, the particles are uniformly distributed in space, with a Gaussian momentum distribution of zero mean and standard deviation $1$. In the second one, the particles are Gaussian distributed in both position and momentum, i.e. the particles are concentrated around $x = 0$.

The first one has the issue that it is not normalizable: the integral is infinite so there is no non-zero $C$ that will give you the correct integral. But if you require the distribution to be normalized/normalizable, there are workarounds such as assuming the spatial distribution is uniform only in a finite region $|x| < L/2$, and zero elsewhere.

Comment: Hi. When you say that for the first one the particles are uniformly distributed. Do you mean that in $dx$ there will be $dx/L$ particles?

Comment: Also, would a uniform distribution in space (1D) mean that they are *equidistant*?

Comment: Yes, if the particles are uniformly distributed in a region of length $L$, on average there will be $dx/L$ particles in an interval of $dx$. Uniform distribution says nothing about the spacing of particles relative to each other, so it doesn't mean they are equidistant.